# Algo/Formula To Calculate Combination of Ways N Things Can Be Arranged While Meeting Condition

Tags: python, algorithm, math, combinations, formula

### This is not a factorial only problem

If I have 5 items and I wanted to know how many possible ways they could be arranged, the answer is 5! or 120. However my situation is I need to know how many possible ways 5 items could be arranged while the list still meets a certain condition.

If I told you to make a list of heights based off of the requirement `(2,2,5)` where the first two numbers are how many heights you can see looking down the left and right of the list respectively, and the third is how many total items there are you may come up with something that looks like this:

```
               X
               X
           X   X
           X   X   X
2 ---->    X   X X X          <----- 2
           X X X X X
           X X X X X
           A B C D E
```

From the absolute left looking down the list I would only be able to see two of the heights and the same is true from the right, and since there are five items, it is one possible face of the condition `(2,2,5)`.

My problem is figuring out how many ways you could arrange this while keeping the `2` from the left and `2` from the right part, in tact.

Obviously the arrangement `ABCDE` works. You could even have some of the following:

```
ADCBE
ABDCE
ADBCE
ACBDE
ACDBE
```

So figuring out how many different ways there are while keeping the two ends in tact isn't too hard it would just be `3!` I believe. However it gets interesting when you change up the sides. For example these combinations would work:

AEBCD
ABECD

And this is because we are assuming in this particular situation C is the tallest and can cover up all of the ones to the left of it so putting a short one to the right of it would still maintain visibility of `2` from both sides so long as the third highest one is in between the farthest left, and the highest one.

With this rhetoric implemented, it makes sense to stress that the only information an algorithm or formula can get is simply `(2,2,5)` so you cannot put a face on the heights but you do you know there has to be a tallest and a second tallest and so on because they are all unique heights, which is where I came up for the basic posterchild arrangement of my ABCDE.

I am looking for basically any way to find this number in base 10. My thoughts are that based off of the `(2,2,5)` we can create some function that tells us how many variations there cannot be, and we can subtract this from `N!`, or `5!`.

### Edit:

Things we can guarantee ourselves.

- All heights are unique
- The second highest 'value' has to appear on one of the sides.
- The highest value can never appear on any absolute sides
- More?